# How to find coustom history in Google Fit

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit

I working on Android application for wristband devices and this devices have specific BLE protocol, Google Fit can't work with it directly.
And I add to my application Google Fit HistoryAPI, now when I receive steps,distance,calories from device, I store it in Fit server via API by using code like this

```
DataSource DSTEP_SOURCE = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setAppPackageName(App.mContext.getPackageName())
                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setName("GeekFit Steps")
                .setStreamName("GeekFit Steps")
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build();
// Steps data
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(DSTEP_SOURCE);
DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint();
dataPoint.setTimestamp(sport.getTimestamp(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(sport.getSteps() - lastSport.getSteps());
dataSet.add(dataPoint);
Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the dataset in the History API");
com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
         Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// Before querying the data, check to see if the insertion succeeded.
if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
    return null;
}
Log.i(TAG, "Fit insert Success!");
```

I have success callbacks, but cant find inserted data on Google Fit application, just see steps counted by mobile device and that's all.

What I do wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?